# Can you claim access to profiles of a family member that passed away?

Tags: support

I want to know what happens with the data on the internet left by people that passed away? Can family members or good friends claim access to the files or profiles? How do companies  like Facebook and Google deal with such requests of family members?

Can I ask this question on Information Security? Is this question on topic or not?

Comment: Here is the question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/37155/485